# For Loop for finding and deleting rows

Tags: excel, vba

So i have an excel wb where i store data.

In column A is the Date, In column D is the Activity,In column R is the Destination, In column F is the Name. 
I need a VBA Code to check these 4 columns if there are rows that are the same.
I has to check the date, then check the Activity and etc.. For the Last Row and go up till the first. And if it finds duplicates it should delete the older one (that's why i think it should be from the last row to the first).

I decided to write a code in the DB

```
Sub DeleteRows()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To LastRow Step 1
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(Cells(1, "B"), Cells(i, "B")), Cells(i, 
"B")) < LastRow Then
    Rows(i + 1).Delete
End If
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Now i can't think of a way to finish it. 
i want to keep the ones that are in red 
[image]

Comment: I edited it and wrote the code that i have.

Comment: Looks good! I voted to reopen your question based on your provided code.

Comment: Well, without VBA: Create an helper column, values 1 till <lastrow>, order your table based on that column from largest to smallest. Then remove duplicates based on your 4 columns. I think you could replicate this in VBA, however, putting this in a `Dictionary` could also be good?

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: 1) Add an **extra column** to your table > 2) Fill the column with values from 1 to 1000 (or whichever is your last row > 3) Sort this column **largest to smallest** (this reversed your data order) > Now remove duplicates based on your 4 columns that you indicated.

Comment: I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
    Public Sub Delete_duplicate_rows()

        Dim R1 As Long, R2 As Long

        R1 = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Do While R1 > 1
            R2 = R1 - 1
            Do While R2 > 1
                If Cells(R1, 1) = Cells(R2, 1) Then
                    If Cells(R1, 4) = Cells(R2, 4) Then
                        If Cells(R1, 6) = Cells(R2, 6) Then
                            If Cells(R1, 13) = Cells(R2, 13) Then
                                Rows(R2).Delete
                                R1 = R1 - 1

                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
                R2 = R2 - 1
            Loop
            R1 = R1 - 1
        Loop

    End Sub
```